# Help with Simple Algebra in Generalized Binomial Option Pricing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working through [this](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/021215/examples-understand-binomial-option-pricing-model.asp) explanation of the Binomial Option Pricing Model and I am stuck on one step. In particular this is where they equate the present value of an example portfolio at time of expiry (by discounting at the risk free rate) with the value of the current holding at instantiation, $sX-c$, where $s=\frac{P_{up}-P_{down}}{X(u-d)}$.

So we have:

$$
\frac{P_{up}-P_{down}}{u-d}-c = e^{-rt}\biggl[\frac{P_{up}-P_{down}}{u-d}u-P_{up}\biggr]
$$

They solve for $c$ and end up with:

$$
c = \frac{e^{-rt}}{u-d}\big[(e^{-rt}-d)P_{up}+(u-e^{-rt})P_{down}\big]
$$

I think this should be very simple but I have gone through it 4 times and keep ending up with:

$$
c = \frac{e^{-rt}}{u-d}\big[(e^{rt}-d)P_{up}+(u-e^{rt})P_{down}\big]
$$

Any help would be appreciated. What is wrong with me!

Comment: Since there is no term that looks like $ e^{-2rt} P_{up}$, their formula is (most likely) wrong. Yours looks correct (and they just had a typo).

Comment: Hi Calvin, thank you for the comment. I think you are correct, I have just gone through the next section and their result doesn't make sense. Thank you for the quick, helpful input!